# why $scope.$apply not working in angular js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ui-select

I am using ui select in my demo .I am using `$scope.$apply()` to update the view but it not working.

- I have few option in my UI multiple select.There is one condition when user select `Nicole` it blank or remove previous selected value and set only `Nicole` value in model.
- here is my plunker

http://plnkr.co/edit/eVXVzlRXJ4KUZaNjID6P?p=preview

Step to reproduce

- select `Amalie` from drop down .so model value is `12`
- then select `Nicole` from drop down .So I remove all previous value from model so now model value only `43` .But it not remove `Amelia` from view why ?
  I used $scope.$apply also.

  ```
  $scope.OnClickSelect = function(item, $select) {
      if ($scope.restrictNames.indexOf(item.name) != -1) {
          $scope.multipleDemo = [];
          $scope.$apply();
          $scope.multipleDemo.push(item.age);
      } else {
          if ($scope.multipleDemo.indexOf(43) != -1) {
              $select.selected = [];

          } else {
              $scope.multipleDemo.push(item.age);
          }
      }

  }
  ```

Comment: look at the first part in this section https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/wiki/FAQs

Comment: and here http://stackoverflow.com/a/29907853/736967

Comment: $scope.$apply is not running because the digest cycle was already running....Also...the component you are using is for adding tags, why would you use tags to remove them? why not some sort of dropdown? check the js file for the component, maybe is not allowing you to play around with something is not intended for that?

Comment: please share any fiddle

Comment: can you tell us what you want to achieve leaving $apply() aside for a while , and why is there a specific cond for Nicole and Amaile.Is that your requirement?

Comment: @user944513 Did you read the links Ronnie previously posted? That second link seems to fit your situation.